# Этимология слова «стихотворение»

Tags: этимология

Это слово образовано от *стихии* *творить* (что-либо) или от *тишины, спокойствия и уединения с самим собой*?

А может, от чего-то другого...

Answer (score 2):

У меня ассоциации не со стихией, а со стихами. Может, стихотворение - это **творение в стихах**?

Стихия - что-то неорганизованное, не подчиняющееся воле человека, а  стих (настроение) - как-то связано, конечно, с настроем, с вдохновением (на него нашёл ... стих), но творить это настроение - это не стихотворение, это что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл здесь *противоположен* "стихии": изначально это о форме упорядочивания. Приводимая Фасмером https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-12740.htm этимология слова **стих** от древнегреческого слова со значением **ряд** указывает на *военные* построения: https://www.stihi.ru/2010/11/05/8743 Со временем слово стало обозначать форму организации речи и текста. Стихотворение - сложное слово с очевидным значением "сотворённых стихов".

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Преображенского А. Г. видим, что стих это:
и религиозная песня, и настроение, и строка. Но никак не стихия. Корень "стих" имеет греческие корни.   "Стихотворение" происходит от двух лексем : "стих" и "творение". По сути это слово обозначает творческий процесс - творение стиха, но со временем произошла некая семантическая трансформация и стихотворение стало синонимом стиху. 
Стих, P. стих versus;
 народ. песня религиознаго со-
держания; настроение, располо-
жение духа; стишок; стихотворец, 
стихотворство, стихотворение,
стихотворный; стихоплет - плохой
етихотворец; стихира - род цер-
ковного песнопения на утрене
 вечерне; стихирар книга стих-
аир; стиховн стихира ,с запе-
вом из псалма.
др. и сс. стих , стихира, сти
хера, стиховьна, стихирарь; стихо
логисат петь по стихам.
— И гр. Οτίχος ряд, строка,
стих; в соврем. издрус ; сти
хир гр. ύτιχηρόν; стихирар гр.
ύτιχΐ]ράρι(ον) (Фасмер, Эт. III,
192). Интересн значени стих - 
настроение, расположение духа;
 выр. «На него такой стих
находит, нашел» внезапная охота
 чему-либо; блажь, придирчи-
вость и т. п. Это и значение -
строка, линия, полоса.